# Difference between "wer" and "jemand"

Tags: synonym

Recently I've seen that "wer" can mean "someone" in some contexts- e.g. "Kann wer spielen?" meaning "Can someone play?" Is it a synonym of "jemand" here or are there contexts where one should say "wer" instead of "jemand"? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "wer" instead of "jemand" is only possible (and, actually, pretty common) in colloquial or regional speech. It isn't commonly used in writing or "elevated conversation".

Background: "wer" is either a *relative* pronoun or an *interrogative* pronoun. "Kann wer spielen" uses it as an *indefinite* pronoun, which it isn't.

Comment: The second paragraph seems to contradict the first.

Comment: @DavidVogt I'm not sure in what way?

Comment: The first paragraph suggests indefinite *wer* exists, the second claims it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidVogt But that's exactly the point: Indefinite "wer" exists in colloquial language only.

Comment: I think that could be worded clearer. In three sentences, we have three different predicates: *is (only) possible*, *is (not) used*, *does (not) exist*. Indefinite *wer* clearly exists, but isn't used (or accepted) equally in different registers.

Comment: @DavidVogt Isn't it common that different sentences have different predicates? I'm a bit lost on where you see a problem.

Comment: Wer ohne Sünde ist, werfe den ersten Stein.

Comment: @userunknown das ist die Verwendung als Relativpronomen. "Kann wer spielen" ist kein Relativpronomen.

Comment: It's not clear from the answer if there is a difference in meaning between *wer* and *jemand* other than one is colloquial and one is standard. This is answered in the usage notes [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemand) though.